# natbib superscript not working

Tags: natbib

My understanding is that `\usepackage[super]{natbib}` should result in citations in a superscript format, but this doesn't appear to be working for me in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}[10pt]
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{}{;}

\begin{document}
\title{Debug Document}
\date{}
\maketitle

cite: \cite{mycite}

cite: \textsuperscript{\cite{mycite}}

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{mycite}
Authors.
\newblock {Title}.
\newblock {\em Journal}, 2001.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The output I get is the following:

[image: Generated PDF]

Note that the first `cite` is not actually a superscript.  Wrapping the cite in `\textsuperscript` makes it (hackishly) do what I want, but I'd prefer to figure out what is actually wrong with `natbib`.

On a previous machine (which I no longer have access to) this worked just fine, so I'm wondering if it is some library incompatibility, but I have no idea how to debug such a thing.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the fixed version of your MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{;}

\begin{document}
\title{Debug Document}
\date{}
\maketitle

cite: \cite{mycite}

cite: \textsuperscript{\cite{mycite}}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{mycite}
Authors.
\newblock {Title}.
\newblock {\em Journal}, 2001.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

You have to use:

```
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{;}
```

instead of:

```
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{}{;}
```

i.e. `n` should be replaced by `s` in the fourth option of `\bibpunct` command.

Comment: +1. Since `s` is specified in the fourth argument of `\bibpunct`, it seems unnecessary to also specify the option `super` when `natbib` is loaded initially.

Comment: Thanks!  Actually, the original .cls file that I'm using (didn't show in the post to keep things minimal) used the `a` option to `\bibpunct`, which is clearly wrong.  Yet this worked on the previous machine I was using.  So my best guess is that previous versions of `natbib` ignored that argument when `super` is specified (though I figured it wasn't frequently updated).  But now, yes, I agree with @Mico, specifying `super` as an option to `natbib` is pointless if it also needs to be specified to `\bibpunct`.